# How can I dynamically set a site's referer in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm not sure how to make this question reproducible because it requires having a Vimeo paid (or on a free trial) account.

Vimeo recently changed their UI for creators and made it harder to access one of the pages I use every day.

From `https://vimeo.com/manage/videos` there is a table with links to individual videos. The URL for each link is something like `https://vimeo.com/55555555555555/settings`.

If you click, it sends you to Page A: `https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/55555555555555`.

Then, there's a button that sends you to the page I actually need (Page B): `https://vimeo.com/manage/55555555555555/general`.

The problem is that when I enter the URL for Page B directly in my browser, it redirects me back to Page A.

Strangely, the back/forward buttons navigate between pages A and B, and the refresh button also stays in Page B. But if I copy Page B's URL, open a new tab and paste it, it sends me back to Page A.

To figure out what's going on, I looked in the network tab of the Chrome Developer tools and found that the first request from Page A to page B looks like this:

[image]

But then, if I paste that URL in a different tab, I get a 302:

[image]

I've diffed both requests:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent the 302 behavior?

Comment: I've noticed this annoying change too. Although this isn't a true answer to your question, it might still be useful for your daily workflow as it will at least save you a full page refresh. The redirect only seems to happen for the general section of the settings page. You can still access any of the other "tabs" directly, e.g. https://vimeo.com/manage/XXXX/collaboration. Not a perfect solution, but it beats the alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a vimeo account and thus can not test it. Ultimately, the server could use any parts of the diff, but I'd expect it to use the referrer.

Does the page always direct you back if you [completely disable setting the referrer in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/450348/how-do-you-block-referrer-logging-in-google-chrome)? If so, using a [plugin to forge your referrer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin) could solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. This is almost what I need. It does indeed work if I hard code site `https://vimeo.com/manage/XXXXXX/general` to use referer `https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/XXXXXX`. The problem is that I need XXXXXX to be dynamic and apparently, [regex capture groups are not allowed](https://keepa.com/refererControlDisqus.html#comment-4540982316).

Comment: Hm, I don't know of any other plugins for chrome that could do this. There was [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/138338/referral-with-regex-for-firefox) on how to do it on firefox, but it didn't give any nice solutions, either.

Would setting up some kind of proxy be an option for you? It might be relatively easy to build one that changes the referrer as you need it. [Similar code for e.g. pyproxy can be found on the internet](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py/blob/develop/proxy/plugin/redirect_to_custom_server.py)

Answer (score -1):

Unlike 301 redirects which are permanent, 302 are not. The web server displaying 302 errors should redirect the browser and take you to the new location immediately. It should be noted that HTTP 302 status code is due to the web server and not the web browser. There is no control at your end.

Comment: The redict only happens if the HTTP referrer is not set to what the server expects. This question is about how to correctly set the referrer when accessing this specific site.